# Cannot listen/handle EventEmitter in callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multipart

Using [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) to work with MongoDB, however when trying to handle events (ie. parsing multipart uploads with [Formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable)) emitted in the query callback, no luck. Any idea why, or a fix?

*Models*

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

function User() {
  return mongoose.model('users', new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    email: String,
    name: String
  }));
}

exports = module.exports = User;
```

*Server*

```
/** Example HTTP server
  */

var http = require('http'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    formidable = require('formidable'),
    models = require('./models');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var User = new models.User();
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  User.findOne({ username: 'wayoutmind' }, function(error, user) {
    // Does not print to console, Event listener blackhole?
    form.on('field', function(name, value) {
      console.log(name + ':' + value);
    });
    form.parse(request);
  });
}).listen(1337);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm that form parsing is working independently, i.e. if you omit the call to the database (findOne) ?

If so, you might want to try setting up your `form.on()` callbacks and run `form.parse()` *before* making the call to `User.findOne()`? The form object could be internally listening for `"data"` events on request which have already happened by the time the callback from `findOne()` is fired.

You could also try using request.pause() and request.resume() (hackier):

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  request.pause();
  User.findOne({ username: 'wayoutmind' }, function(error, user) {
       form.on('field', function(name, value) {
       console.log(name + ':' + value);
     });
     request.resume();
     form.parse(request);
  });
}).listen(1337);
```

Comment: The parsing is working independently and form object is apparently  missing those "data" events. Suggestions on how to use the result returned by User.findOne callback in the form.on('field') callback?

Comment: There's a bunch of ways to deal with this, for example you could just push the data into an array each time the `"field"` callback fires so you buffer all the data that needs to be handled. Then add an event handler to `form.on("end")` and do your processing there, all the data from the form you need is saved in the array ready to be used.. Also using a library like step.js or async.js here might make this much easier.